# using sed to parse log to eliminate lines by regex

Tags: sed

I would like to be able to clean up a log file using sed and regex

a) any line which matches /\d{13,13},\d*,[\w\s]+,.+\n/ I would like to delete
b) remove any empty lines that are remaining.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -re '/\d{13,13},\d*,[\w\s]+,.+$/d' -e '/^$/d' logfile
```

Comment: You need to either use the `-r` flag for perl regex, or escape these characters: `{}+`. You might want to use `$` instead of `\n` in the first expression.

Comment: You might want to use `/^\s*$/d` for the second expression, since empty lines might contain some whitespace.